# Handy shortcut to run the application I've just installed?

Tags: finder

1. Download `.dmg`
2. Double click
3. Drag to `Applications` folder
4. CMD + space to run it

Is it everyone or just me, the indexing didn't pick it up... Is there a handy shortcut to run the application I've just installed?

Comment: Indexing is pretty instant for me: I can spotlight an app I've just dropped into the Applications folder. (And it's definitely that one, not the one in the DMG...!!)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the app's signature status [& from a .dmg rather than from the App Store this is likely to be quarantined], you are probably better off just going to the Applications folder - start typing the app name & it will be selected. Then *right click* & select Open. This will invoke Gatekeeper & allow you to run it, no matter the signature.

Alternatively, wait a few minutes for Spotlight to have indexed it. [You may still have to go back to method 1 if you want to clear the quarantine flag].